Error Integrating Module Federation in Next.js 14 with App Directory: NextFederationPlugin
I am working on developing a micro-frontend application using Next.js 14.2.5 along with Module Federation. I have created two applications using the following commands:
npx create-next-app mf-host
npx create-next-app mf-widgets

I’m using the app directory structure in both applications. Here’s how I configured the next.config.mjs files for each application:
mf-widgets - next.config.mjs:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
import { NextFederationPlugin } from '@module-federation/nextjs-mf';

process.env.NEXT_PRIVATE_LOCAL_WEBPACK = true;

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  transpilePackages: ["ui"],
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new NextFederationPlugin({
        name: 'widgets',
        filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
        exposes: {
          './TopNavigation': './components/topNavigation/TopNavigation',
        },
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
};

export default nextConfig;


mf-host - next.config.mjs:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
import { NextFederationPlugin } from '@module-federation/nextjs-mf';

process.env.NEXT_PRIVATE_LOCAL_WEBPACK = true;

const WIDGETS_APP_URL =
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WIDGET_APP_URL || 'http://localhost:3000';

const remotes = (isServer) => {
  const location = isServer ? 'ssr' : 'chunks';
  return {
    widgets: `widgets@${WIDGETS_APP_URL}/_next/static/${location}/remoteEntry.js`,
  };
};

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new NextFederationPlugin({
        name: 'host',
        filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
        remotes: remotes(isServer),
      })
    );
    return config;
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

However, when I try to run the mf-widgets application, I receive the following error:
▲ Next.js 14.2.5
Local: http://localhost:3000
✓ Starting...
Error: App Directory is not supported by nextjs-mf. Use only pages directory, do not open git issues about this at NextFederationPlugin.validateOptions...
My understanding is that this error suggests that nextjs-mf doesn't support the app directory in Next.js 14. Is there a way to make this work with the app directory, or do I need to revert to the pages directory structure? If so how to do it?
Any guidance on how to resolve this issue or an alternative approach would be greatly appreciated.
I tried renaming the app directory to pages in my Next.js project. After doing this, I expected my application to function as usual, and when navigating to the deployment at localhost:3000 (which is a module federation host), I expected the default page to load correctly. However, instead of seeing my app, I encountered a 404 Page Not Found error.

If you're running the npx create-next-app temp-app command and want to organize your Next.js project in page structure(follow the traditional structure for Next.js applications), here’s how we can set it up:
When prompted with:

"Would you like to use the src/ directory?" - Choose No
"Would you like to use the App Router?" - Choose No

After the setup, created my widgets inside the components folder. This allowed me to continue with the nextjs micro front end.
But still, it seems webpack cannot used with the latest app router structure. Anyone has an idea how to proceed with the latest nextjs routing structure with the micro front ends.
